# How to pass onChange event inside template literal in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to pass an onChange event inside a template literal in a react project.
I have some inputs and im trying to change the value based on what the user typed in and for now just print it out inside of paragraph element, my end goal is to save all input information and print it out inside of a new card.

This is my attempt and code

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("")


    let output = `<div class="card create-card">
            <div class="card-image"></div>
          <div class="card-text card-text-area">
              
              <h2>Create new spot</h2>
              <form>
              <label>Spot title</label>
              <input
              required
              value="${title}"
              onChange="${(e) =>{setTitle(e.target.value)}}"
              type="text" 
              >
              </input>
            
              <button>Add card</button>

              <p>${ title }</p>
          </div>
          </div>`;
```

It seems like its an easy fix but cant really find the right syntax when used inside of a template literal.

I dont get any errors nor no output

Comment: Why you don't use JSX?

Comment: Why would you use a template literal for this. The function you provided does not provide any meaningful return value which you would want to display. Just use `{}` to escape to be able to use JavaScript. Change to `onChange={(e) =>{setTitle(e.target.value)}`, which will do the job. By the way the same holds true for `title`. You should read the [React docs on JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: @y.rashi YEs i just realized i dont need to use template literal and just make it jsx in a seperate component. And it works fine thx

Answer (score 0):

this might work
declare your function before your output and pass it

```
const changeHandler = (e) =>{setTitle(e.target.value)};
.
.
.
onChange="${changeHandler(e)}"
```

Comment: Tried make it that way but could not print out title this way either. Thx